# How to get route plan with certain distance with pgRouting?

Tags: postgis, pgrouting, spatial-database, routing

I am working for a project. I have a road network which has been imported in PostgreSQL/PostGIS database. I can query shortest path between two points. I want to get route plan with certain distance. Suppose, I want to go from point A to point B. There may have different way to go from point A to B. But, I want to fix the length, suppose, 10 km. That means, I want to know the route plan to go from point A to point B but in 10 km range. Is it possible to get this kind of query using pgRouting? Or I should use any other tools? If it is possible how should I write the query?

Note: in my database table 'route', i have 'gid', 'source', 'target', 'cost' etc columns.

Thanks, in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, I don't think pgRouting can do this. Shortest path algorithms minimize costs. If you want a fix length there would be too many possibilities.

K-shortest path is an algorithm that returns alternative routes (someone is currently working on an implementation as far as I know). But this still wouldn't allow you define the length.

Comment: I agree, and there may not even be any routes at exactly 10 km length.